# Passing A Parameter to a Thread using Lambda Expression not working correctly

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass more than one parameter to a thread.

I am only testing with one parameter though, and the Lambda Expression is not passing the valeis of the parameters correctly. The *ParameterizedThreadStart* is working correctly, but I can **only pass one object** variable and not more and this limits me.

I have made an example for each and the outputs of the Lambda Expression method outputs are incorrect.

For both cases, numOfPortThreads = 2

Using *ParameterizedThreadStart*

```
    public void InitializePorts(int numOfPortThreads)
        {
            Thread[] tPortArr = new Thread[numOfPortThreads];

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfPortThreads; i++)
            {

                tPortArr[i] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(new PortSim().PortRun)); 
                tPortArr[i].Start(i);
            }
        }
```

In "PortSim.cs"

```
public void PortRun(object portID)
        {

            portStopWatch.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("This is Port {0}", portID);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

---

The output in that case is:

This is Port 0
This is Port 1

---

However, using Lambda Expression,

```
public void InitializePorts(int numOfPortThreads)
        {
            Thread[] tPortArr = new Thread[numOfPortThreads];

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfPortThreads; i++)
            {

                tPortArr[i] = new Thread( () => new PortSim().PortRun(i));
                tPortArr[i].Start();
            }
        }
```

In "PortSim.cs"

```
public void PortRun(int portID)
        {

            portStopWatch.Start();


            Console.WriteLine("This is Port {0}", portID);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

---

The output in that case is:

This is Port 2
This is Port 2

---

What is wrong with the second example? Why does it yield incorrect results?

Comment: I found the answer in these threads as well. Please close the question if it is possible. Thanks!

Comment: The question _has_ been closed already. You may feel free to delete it yourself with the _"delete"_ link at the bottom of your post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce local variable like this.

```
public void InitializePorts(int numOfPortThreads)
        {
            Thread[] tPortArr = new Thread[numOfPortThreads];

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfPortThreads; i++)
            {
                int j = i;
                tPortArr[j] = new Thread( () => new PortSim().PortRun(j));
                tPortArr[j].Start();
            }
        }
```

you may be wondering why just google closures in c#

Comment: Side note: if you are not planning to make answer better than many duplicates you should just vote to close instead...

Comment: I was still googling and found out this article online: https://www.martyndavis.com/?p=405. It explained it in details. Thanks for your answer though. I really needed to know why this is happening.